# Windows Taking too long to be clean installed on ssd

Tags: partitioning, ssd, mbr, gpt, windows-10-v1903

I recently bought a Lenovo Ideapad 130 with No OS Pre-installed on it.
It has a HDD and a 120Gb SSD installed on it. 
When i tried to install windows 10 on It, I figured out that it's taking too long to install.
Also after the installation was finished, the Windows was operating so Slow.
I installed the last drivers but there was no difference.
I installed the same windows on another system just 2 days before this happened with no problem.
note: the installation media was a USB-flash drive and i used Rufus to create it. I chose GPT partition style and FAT32 file system (Rufus Default setting for GPT)
What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't just use the Media Creation Tool instead of Rufus to make the USB installer? Also, are you 100% sure you installed Windows on the SSD and not on the HDD by mistake?

Comment: You are very vague with the terms "long" and "slow". What do you mean by "too long to install" and "Windows was operating so Slow". How many minutes did take to installing Windows 10? How long does Windows 10 take to (i.e.) reboot?

Comment: @wrecclesham I usually use Rufus with Because i've always used Rufus with no Specific reason. And I'm 100% Sure I installed the windows on SSD.

Comment: @MadMike Based on my experience Windows installation process usually will not take more than 10-15 minutes( Specially on SSD). but in this case it took nearly 1 hour of my time. and after installation it was so slow that for example opening start menu was taking 10 seconds. i checked task manager and i saw the usage of SSD was 100%.( with no softwares installed or running). Booting and restarting process were taking approximately 3-4 minutes. while now that i applied an image on it, it's taking just a few seconds.

Comment: @E.njf your comment to me should be part of the question.

Comment: @MadMike Sorry for my long comment. do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @E.njf I've updatet my workstation to 1903 at work. Even though it's a fast machine on a fast Internet connection it took about 3 hours to update. After the update windows was busy reindexing its search index of the hdd content. All I can offer is advice to simply look at the taskmanager. Look at it and *update* your question. Like this you will improve the probability of someone giving you a good answer. Also you might thus help others having the same issue.